# Where can all of Poppi's Technical Manuals be found?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

So, to upgrade Poppi, you need technical manuals to learn how to make parts for her. I've really only found one in the old factory in Mor Ardain. Trying to find all of them so I can make Tora a more versatile character, instead of just a tank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there are only 5 technical manuals to find. The locations of each are as follows:

Nimble Nopon Get Girls

> Uraya - Head - Greatmaw Rapids - if I remember right, it's in the water.

Artificial Blade Report

> Mor Ardain - Old Factory - Work Observation Tower - it's in a chest on a ledge and around a corner. It's visible from the floor.
>
>  [image: artificial blade report chest]

Ether R&D Revolution

> Kingdom of Tantal - Theoscaldia Palace - Hall of Reception - Storage Room - it's in a chest

Robolab Club Quarterly

> Land of Morytha - Fallen Skyscraper - Highway 8 - go up the building, walk south along the highway, and then west across the connecting highway

Hypertech Made Easy

> World Tree - Lower Level - Sky Bridge - in a chest guarded by a unique, requiring, I think, 6 fortitude and X lockpicking

Credits to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xenoblade_Chronicles/comments/7ipymi/poppis_technical_manual_locations/) for helping me find the last 2, and reminding me where I found the first one.